# Map function is not working properly?

Tags: haskell

Map functions is not working on this line

`compPic  (a:as) = map (compL a) as`

It just work on single string but not on a list of string can you find error.

```
compL  :: String -> String
compL  bs = [a | b <- bs, a <- 
                if (b == ' ')
                   then "X"
                 else if (b=='X')
                   then " "
                   else [b]]


compPic :: [String] -> [String]
compPic  [] = []
compPic  (a:as) = map (compL a) as
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `map` in `Prelude`:

```
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Here, we see that `map` is defined to pass each value in a list to the function that's being applied. Further, we don't need a base case because `map` handles the recursion. Thus, you should rewrite `compPic` as:

```
compPic :: [String] -> [String]
compPic as = map compL as
```

Or, eta-reduced:

```
compPic = map compL
```

Comment: Well you explain very technically . Thank you @mnoronha . You are kind :)